# Dev-C++ - [Build Error] [main.o] Error 2816

Tags: c++, windows, windows-10, dev-c++, windows-98

I started a new project and I am trying to compile using defaults on Microsoft Windows 10. I need to compile for Windows 98 for a specific project. The compiler shows the following error message `[Build Error] [main.o] Error 2816`.

This is the contents of `main.cpp`:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have no idea what this error means, and I did not find anything using Google. Any ideas?

**Edit - Compile log**

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Building Makefile: "C:\Projects\prog\Makefile.win"
Executing  make...
make.exe -f "C:\Projects\prog\Makefile.win" all
gcc.exe -c main.c -o main.o -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include"   

gcc.exe main.o  -o "prog.exe" -L"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib"  

gcc.exe: Internal error: Aborted (program collect2)
Please submit a full bug report.
See <URL:http://www.mingw.org/bugs.shtml> for instructions.

make.exe: *** [prog.exe] Error 1

Execution terminated
```

Comment: I'll bet that the message you show is not the *only* message. When asking questions about build errors, always include the *full* and *complete* and *unedited* output. Preferably a plain copy-paste of the complete build log.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for your comment. I added a bit more information. I'm not sure if this is what you meant,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer is too late but it would be helpful for the others.

The file "make.exe" is not working well with the Dev C++.
Try to download an old version of Dev C++ with the old set of files for the compiling softwares of MinGW.